# Filtering a ListView in wicket using 2 drop down boxes

Tags: java, listview, filter, wicket, dropdownchoice

I am trying to filter a list that is placed into a listview through the use of 2 drop down boxes.

The first dropdown box is titled price and the second is owner.

I want to be able to select a value in one or more of these drop down boxes and then have the List view re-render with the filtered results.

The trouble is I do not know how to begin this task, would someone be so kind as to enlighten me :D

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best starting point is probably [this](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/choice?2) example: (Source code also available on this page, ChoicePage.java is the name)

First of all, you have to use a dynamic model in your `ListView` that generates the list of items depending on  what you had selected in the dropdown boxes.

Then the basic idea is that you add an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` to the components that control the updates (your two dropdown boxes in your case), and in the `onUpdate()` method of this behaviour you should add the component you want to update to that `AjaxRequestTarget` passed.

Comment: Thanks very much, I really appreciate your answer. Has helped me solve my issue